# Including Keycloak authentication for docker OWASP ZAP container

Tags: docker, keycloak, owasp, zap

I'm working on a solution that involves running a the [owasp/zap2docker-stable](https://hub.docker.com/r/owasp/zap2docker-stable/) image in order to fully scan a web app that implements [Keycloak](https://www.keycloak.org/) for authentication and user management.

If I'm understanding correctly I would need to include a context file with auth details such as user/password, login form target URLs and having the assumption that the authentication method is Form-based when executing a `docker run`. If I'm not wrong and have followed information on the web correctly, it would seem that this context file should be created and exported from the ZAP UI app.

My questions are as follows:

- Is it confirmed that Keycloak uses form-based authentication?
- Am I correct in understanding that the context file has to be created, exported and supplied to docker run commands for this to happen?
- Are there any specific steps that I would need to take note of when creating the context file?
- How could I confirm that the login process occurred successfully?

Comment: `Keycloak for authentication` is very vague definition. Keycloak offers SAML and OIDC SSO protocol. Each protocol has own variations (flows, IDP/SP initiated, ...). Keycloak may have implemented also optional/mandatory mutual (X.509) TLS authentication (so it won't be form based at all).

Comment: Did you succeed in building the Docker image? Can you publish the image or the ZAP scripts you used?

Comment: Old but yes, keycloak does use form based authentication, and no, you don't need the UI to create the context, you can extend the official image with a python hook in which the context is created.

Comment: I've created a PR on the [zaproxy/community-scripts](https://github.com/zaproxy/community-scripts/pull/282) repo with an example [scan-hook](https://www.zaproxy.org/docs/docker/scan-hooks) for building the context and performing form-based authentication.

Answer (score 1):

No idea about Keycloak but you are right about the ZAP context file. Although if you can authenticate to your app using a header then you can just set that via an env var.

ZAP maintains stats - see https://www.zaproxy.org/docs/internal-statistics/ and search for "auth" in the key. You can test those via scan hooks https://www.zaproxy.org/docs/docker/scan-hooks/

Alternatively you can wait until the Automation Framework fully supports authentication - thats hopefully going to be soon but no ETA. In any case you'll still need to set up and test the auth in the ZAP desktop first.

Comment: I know you were refering to stats via API on the docker container but is there a way to confirm login succeeded in ZAP UI 2.11? I'd like to check that login is going through on both the creation of the context file and then after running the container, so I'm missing the first check.

Comment: Also the web app uses cors to authenticate with Keycloak. As I stated, Keycloak seemingly uses form based auth and returns a bearer token. Is there any additional setting I would need to include to manage both cross site logins and bearer tokens?

Comment: Yes. ZAP only 'understand' simple auth scenarios. For keycloak you will need to manage everything (voa ZAP scripts). ZAP will do what you tell it to, so if your scripts handle  everything correctly then it will all work. I've recorded some vidoes - search for "auth" on https://www.zaproxy.org/videos-list/